# "HTTP listener not registered" using OrientDB Docker image

Tags: configuration, orientdb

I'm using latest [Docker image of OrientDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb/) (`3.0.0m2` but this is also happening with `2.2.26` image) and when I try to run it using the 3 volume mappings (`config`, `databases` and `backup`) + the `ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` environment variable, I have the following error and can't access to OrientDB Studio:

```
2017-09-11 20:28:44:304 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'orientdb-studio-3.0.0m2.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]Error on installing dynamic plugin 'studio'
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: HTTP listener not registered while installing Static Content command
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.registerStaticDirectory(OServerPluginManager.java:224)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.installDynamicPlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:383)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:211)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugins(OServerPluginManager.java:309)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.startup(OServerPluginManager.java:95)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:1064)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:400)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:46)
```

I'm launching the image using the following command:

```bash
docker run -it --rm -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480 \
    -v /run/shm/docker_data/config:/orientdb/config \
    -v /run/shm/docker_data/databases:/orientdb/databases \
    -v /run/shm/docker_data/backup:/orientdb/backup \
    -e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=orientdb_root_password \
    orientdb:3.0.0m2
```

It actually generates a `orientdb-server-config.xml` file in the `config` volume that contains this (and is missing any HTTP listener indeed):

```xml
<network>
    <protocols>
        <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary" name="binary"/>
    </protocols>
    <listeners>
        <listener protocol="binary" socket="default" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="127.0.0.1"/>
    </listeners>
</network>
```

Does somebedoy know how to make the Studio really work?

Comment: Don&#39;t provide an empty config folder, please. https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb/

Comment: @RobertoFranchini… how is this not provided as an actual answer / accepted? Thank you: it's a simple thing but is in fact the source of the problem!